# [] is not defined in Map<String, Dynamic>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hey devs Iam trying to make a dropdown menu of categories from firebase.

look this code

```
_getCategories() async {
    List<DocumentSnapshot> data = await _categoryService.getCategory();
    print(data.length);
    setState(() {
      categories = data;
      _currentCategory =  categories[0].data['category'];
    });
  }
```

Here the error is I cant assign 'category' to data, there it is showing me error. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
   setState(() {
      categories = data;
      _currentCategory =  categories[0].data['category'];
    });
```

into this:

```
   setState(() {
      categories = data;
      _currentCategory =  categories[0].data()['category'];
    });
```

In the latest update for the firebase plugins, `data()` is a method now.